# Command line like widget in swing

Tags: java, swing, command-line

I am trying to create a small Java program that has a simple command line like widget not so different from that of idle. I was originally planning to use a JTextArea and try to detect when someone presses enter, but I was wondering if there would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is a "text box". I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is more stylish way to have `ENTER` to terminate. If you want to have along with some button that will not easy as idle one. I suggestion you have `JTEXTAREA`, you user can have wide area to see the things that they have keyed. I do not have much idea on this :) thanks